# Moving an application from Django 1.4 to 1.8

Tags: python, django, git, python-2.7

I had a previous project running on Django 1.4 and I am now trying to "revive it".

**Specifically my system at that time was OS-X and running BITNAMI DJANGO STACK 1.4.6 (Python 2.7)** **. I have pulled the source code from the Git repository into a fresh install of BITNAMI DJANGOSTACK 1.8** https://bitnami.com/stack/django/installer#osx

Ideally, I would have upgraded everything as I went along but I can't find a DJANGOSTACK 1.4.6 download. *To be honest I don't know what would have been the best option for upgrading this application.*

Here is what I have done:

- Cloned code from my Bitbucket repository.
- As expected database was not part of what I had commited to the Git repository. So some data is lost.
- I beleive not having a database backup or maybe changes not commited to Git repository (more likely right?) caused some differences with the schema at some point and it gave me a migration warning.  Migration problem: http://sprunge.us/jIXC
- Ran the suggested `Run 'python manage.py migrate'`
- Some broken links and functionality got fixed. Details are here: http://sprunge.us/QTJF

My main break is with what seems to be an incorrect location to a template? 
(Full traceroute here: http://sprunge.us/hQHK)

`TemplateDoesNotExist at /metrics/metrics_search_form/
metrics/metrics_search_form.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/metrics/metrics_search_form/
Django Version: 1.8.11
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:

metrics/metrics_search_form.html
Exception Location: /Applications/djangostack-1.8.11-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 46
Python Executable:  /Applications/djangostack-1.8.11-0/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.11`

The template does exits but it is at:

```
/metrics/templates/metrics/metrics_search_form.html
```

Is this a new behavior since Django 1.4 to Django 1.8?  If so, how can I fix it.

Should I go about upgrading this project in a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be reading the release notes for each version to see what has changed. I suspect your issue is caused by the new format of the template settings; you should post your existing ones.